# Inkscape not showing svg that displays correctly in browser

Tags: inkscape

This svg from wikimedia, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/OOjs_UI_icon_language-ltr.svg, is visible in web-browers, but shows nothing in Inkscape 0.91r13725

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <title>
    language
  </title>
  <path d="M20 18h-1.44a.61.61 0 0 1-.4-.12.81.81 0 0 1-.23-.31L17 15h-5l-1 2.54a.77.77 0 0 1-.22.3.59.59 0 0 1-.4.14H9l4.55-11.47h1.89zm-3.53-4.31L14.89 9.5a11.62 11.62 0 0 1-.39-1.24q-.09.37-.19.69l-.19.56-1.58 4.19zm-6.3-1.58a13.43 13.43 0 0 1-2.91-1.41 11.46 11.46 0 0 0 2.81-5.37H12V4H7.31a4 4 0 0 0-.2-.56C6.87 2.79 6.6 2 6.6 2l-1.47.5s.4.89.6 1.5H0v1.33h2.15A11.23 11.23 0 0 0 5 10.7a17.19 17.19 0 0 1-5 2.1q.56.82.87 1.38a23.28 23.28 0 0 0 5.22-2.51 15.64 15.64 0 0 0 3.56 1.77zM3.63 5.33h4.91a8.11 8.11 0 0 1-2.45 4.45 9.11 9.11 0 0 1-2.46-4.45z"/>
</svg>
```

Is the problem in Inkscape or in this svg image or am I missing something?

Comment: I just tried opening the SVG in Inkscape 0.92.3 (I think the most recent is now 0.92.4), and it works fine. See screenshot. https://imgur.com/ZF8l87D What I suggest you try is to update to the most recent Inkscape.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job! Please provide an answer, so that I can mark ik solved. I am on a somewhat older Ubuntu 14.04 , had to upgrade through a ppa.

Comment: I'm hesitant to add it as an answer, as questions on tech support are generally off-topic here. Glad it worked for you though.

Comment: Ok. I wonder which other forum on StackExchange would be appropriate for this type of question and would also have the right expertise. Also, it was not clear beforehand that the problem solution was going to be technical.

Comment: You could try [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) perhaps.  As for not being clear it was a tech support question to begin with, yes I agree. The person asking such questions obviously doesn't know this at the time, and that's fine, but the solution can still be "tech support" related, as it was in this question for example.  The problem with tech support questions is that they often involve trial and error solutions, and depend on operating systems, system settings, software versions etc, and are often difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Possibly even [ubuntu.se]...

Comment: "update your inkscape" is a valid answer. If the entire question is invalid (I think no) then it should be closed/deleted but I created an answer as it appears in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inkscape?tab=Unanswered

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is more suitable to Superuser